# How to evaluate a series of dates Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum data if the date of a cell matches in the current month.

Here is the serie of dates as an example and I want to start to sum data starting from Jan 1.
[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @mau I posted an answer. Presuming it works (which it does), I'd be grateful if you clicked accept. Looking through your prior questions, you seem to leave a lot of them unresolved when you've received valid answers. Thanks.

Comment: I'll definetly check your answer. Regarding the other topic, I have no idea how to select resolved, sorry. If you can provide me any tip, I'll be more than happy to click it on my previous questions.

Comment: Sorry, by `unresolved` I simply meant no answer was accepted. It looks like you went back through some of your questions and accepted a few, which I'm sure people appreciated. Thanks,  and good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some dates in column `a` as shown below, with actual data to sum in column `b`, and a cell with a date that represents the month/year you wish to sum (Cell `e1` in the screenshot), then this formula should give you a summation by the proper month.

```
=Sum(FILTER(B:B,year(A:A)=YEAR($E$1),month(A:A)=month($E$1)))
```

[image]